# Fabric-sdk-go 'ld.exe: cannot find -lltdl' error

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

When I try to get the fabric-sdk-go I get the following error:

```
$ go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabric-client
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lltdl
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lltdl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have an idea what is the issue and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message told us that the library [`libltdl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html) which is required by `github.com/miekg/pkcs11` is missing. Although you didn't mention it explicitly, I think you're using MSYS2 as the development environment. Do the following steps to install the missing library.

1. Search for the missing library, type `pacman -Ss ltdl` in MSYS2 terminal to get the *exact package name*. Here, `ltdl` is the keyword related to missing library which we got from error message. You should get something like:

   ```
   msys/libltdl 2.4.6-2  
       A system independent dlopen wrapper for GNU libtool
   ```

   From the result we know that the missing library is provided in `libltdl` package. It seems trivial, but sometimes a library may be provided by more than one package, e.g. a package which has prefix `mingw-w64-i686-*` for 32-bit system and the other with prefix `mingw-w64-x86_64-*` for 64-bit system.
2. Install the package by: `pacman -S libltdl`.
3. Reinstall the `go` package by: `go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabric-client`.